# Newsletter subscriber custom EDIT route Magento 2.3

Tags: custom, magento2.3, routing

I am having custom edit route for core module **Magento_Newsletter** **Subscriber**.

**When I access Edit route loader keeps spinning and doesn't stop.**

> In nginx log I got: 2019/02/11 14:55:33 [error] 15820#15820: *5256
>   access forbidden by rule, client: 127.0.0.1, server: magento2,
>   request: "POST /app/etc/config.php HTTP/1.1", host: "magento2"

**Controller** in path `Pool/Newsletter/Controller/Adminhtml/Subscriber`

```
<?php
namespace Pool\Newsletter\Controller\Adminhtml\Subscriber;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Edit extends \Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Adminhtml\Subscriber
{

    /**
     */
    protected $_pageFactory;

    /**
     * @var $_registry \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_registry;

    /**
     * Edit constructor.
     * @param Action\Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $resultFactory;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $fileFactory);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->_pageFactory->create();

        $segmentId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('subscriber_id');
        $this->_registry->register('subscriber_id', $segmentId);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

**di** in `Pool/Module/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2017 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="DataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber\Collection</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="subscriber_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Newsletter\Model\ResourceModel\Subscriber\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

<preference for="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Adminhtml\Subscriber\Grid" type="Pool\Newsletter\Block\Adminhtml\Subscriber\Grid"/>
</config>
```

**route** in `Pool/Module/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="newsletter" frontName="newsletter">
            <module name="Pool_Newsletter"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**layout**

`Pool/Newsletter/view/adminhtml/layout/newsletter_subscriber_edit.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="subscriber_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

and UI component  `Pool/Newsletter/view/adminhtml/ui_component/subscriber_form.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2017 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">subscriber_form.subscriber_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">subscriber_form.subscriber_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Newsletter Subscriber</item>
        <item name="layout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="type" xsi:type="string">tabs</item>
            <item name="navContainerName" xsi:type="string">left</item>
        </item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Pool\Newsletter\Block\Adminhtml\Subscriber\Edit\BackButton
            </item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">
                Pool\Newsletter\Block\Adminhtml\Subscriber\Edit\DeleteButton
            </item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Pool\Newsletter\Block\Adminhtml\Subscriber\Edit\SaveButton
            </item>
            <item name="save_and_continue" xsi:type="string">
                Pool\Newsletter\Block\Adminhtml\Subscriber\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="subscriber_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Pool\Newsletter\Ui\Component\Form\Subscriber\DataProvider
            </argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">Subscriber_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">subscriber_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">subscriber_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/save"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="subscriber">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">subscriber</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="subscriber_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">subscriber</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="email">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">subscriber</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: **<argument name="name" xsi:type="string">Subscriber_form_data_source</argument>**

uppercase S makes me debug this 5 hours, so it should be **subscriber_form_data_source** .